# error : Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath)

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

All the solutions provided in stack for below error didn't help me. I am using `/p:VisualStudioVersion=10.0 /p:Configuration=Release 
/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=$WORKSPACE\package.zip /t:Package` has Command Line Arguments under Jenkins job to run MSBuild proj. "package.zip" file is not getting created under my work-space if I use `/p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation=some\package.zip` Please suggest me command Line arguments. I am using Upload artifact to Nexus plugin as well to upload this zip file.

`error : Web deployment task failed. (Unknown ProviderOption:DefiningProjectFullPath. Known ProviderOptions are:.)`